# Multipart Request bind Form(@ModelAttribute) in Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, multipartform-data

In Spring Boot2 REST, can a Multipart Request be bound to a Form?

After executing the code below, the Multipart variable of Form is null.

**Form Class:**

```
public class UploadFrom implements Serializable {

  @Data
  private MultipartFile uploadFile;
}
```

**Rest Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public void uploadFile(@ModelAttribute UploadForm form){
        System.out.println(form.getUploadFile()); // --> null!!
    }

}
```

Comment: You can do it in a different way, by using to RequestPart(MultiPart) one for UploadForm and second for File.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different way, by using two RequestPart(MultiPart) one for UploadForm and second for File. Like this :

```
  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public void uploadFile(@RequestPart("form") UploadForm form,
      @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,){
    System.out.println(file);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not works.
It seems to be due to my spring-fox.

Comment: Thanks. 
It seems that the cause was execution from SpringFox.